# Pandas merge / join 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I've got two dataframes i would like to join, however, the dont contain exactly the same rows.

I've got this in the dataframe1

```
test1   1   
test2   3   
test5   4   
test6   5   
test7   6
```

And this in dataframe2

```
test1   4   
test3   5   
test4   6   
test5   3   
test6   3
```

What I would like to achieve is the following

```
    col1    col2
test1   1   4
test2   3    
test3       5
test4       6
test5   4   3
test6   5   3
test7   6
```

or

```
col1    col2
test1   1   4
test2   3   0
test3   0   5
test4   0   6
test5   4   3
test6   5   3
test7   6   0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.merge` with `how='outer'`:

```
In [1539]: df1
Out[1539]: 
     col  val
0  test1    1
1  test2    3
2  test5    4
3  test6    5
4  test7    6

In [1540]: df2
Out[1540]: 
     col  val
0  test1    4
1  test3    5
2  test4    6
3  test5    3
4  test6    3

In [1541]: df1.merge(df2, on='col', how='outer')
Out[1541]: 
     col  val_x  val_y
0  test1    1.0    4.0
1  test2    3.0    NaN
2  test5    4.0    3.0
3  test6    5.0    3.0
4  test7    6.0    NaN
5  test3    NaN    5.0
6  test4    NaN    6.0

In [1542]: df1.merge(df2, on='col', how='outer').fillna(0)
Out[1542]: 
     col  val_x  val_y
0  test1    1.0    4.0
1  test2    3.0    0.0
2  test5    4.0    3.0
3  test6    5.0    3.0
4  test7    6.0    0.0
5  test3    0.0    5.0
6  test4    0.0    6.0
```

Comment: Amazing! this is what im looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Use [merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html), which is inner join by default:

```
pd.merge(dataframe1, dataframe2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Or [join](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html), which is left join by default:

```
dataframe1.join(dataframe2)
```

Or [concat](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html), which is outer join by default:

```
pd.concat([dataframe1, dataframe2], axis=1)
```

Comment: output wasnt exactly what i was after.

Comment: It's is also merging your df as requested.